# Jquery ajax modal form post back to parent form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a query and don't know where to start - I have a image select input field on a form thats populated by an jquery ajax autocomplete. What I would like to do is the following:-

If a user wants to choose an alternative image that's not currently in the dB pop up a modal/lightbox form which contains the upload/editing form.

Once posted I want to pass this data back to the original form field and refresh the data for the autocomplete.

I already have the upload and editing forms working as standalone pages I just want to incorporate the output back into the original form.

1. Is it possible?
2. Can anyone suggest modal/lighbox script that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What data are you trying to retrieve in the parent window? Assuming your using an iframe in your lightbox? If you aren't then you should just be able to set variables and call functions from your upload script output as if it were the same page.

**If you are...**
I don't believe there are any lightbox/modal solutions that support this, I normally incorporate a script like below in my upload script so you can monitor the success/failure of the uploaded file and the data.

```
(function () {
    parent.myClass.imageLocation = $output_your_image_location here;
    return;
)();
```

You can obviously edit this to handle different situations but I always use the parent keyword as I have a similar way of handling uploads in some software I've built recently.